# skewed div with footer doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, sass

So, i'm trying to build a website with skewed sections.

On the main content of the webpage i have no problem at all.

The only problem is on the footer. There is a little blank space between the footer and the bottom of the page caused by the last skewed section. I had already tried to change the position, display, margin, padding of all the elements (body, html, div section, footer, etc.. ) but not seems to be working...

This is the skew code i'm using:

```
$deg: 3deg;
.skew {
    -ms-transform: skewY($deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: skewY($deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: skewY($deg);
}
```

This is the jsfiddle i've made with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/1keobbqc/

I hope you guys can help me on this one here! Thanks!

Comment: is the issue in this fiddle? Cause it looks fine to me

Comment: no issue on my end, Chrome v.39

Comment: Yes it is, try to make the view screen bigger, so you can see it better

Comment: i see now, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/1keobbqc/1/. I've added overflow:hidden to your problematic section.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected, as the screen size grows the angle of your skewed footer will not always be able to stay aligned properly with your small footer. What you can do is use media queries to adjust the angle at certain break points so it stays more level like so:

```
$deg: 3deg;
$deg-media: 8deg;

.skew {
   -ms-transform: skewY($deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: skewY($deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: skewY($deg);
}

.skew-rev {
   -ms-transform: skewY(-$deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: skewY(-$deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   transform: skewY(-$deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px){ 
   .skew {
      -ms-transform: skewY($deg-media); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: skewY($deg-media); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: skewY($deg-media);
   }

   .skew-rev {
      -ms-transform: skewY(-$deg-media); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: skewY(-$deg-media); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: skewY(-$deg-media);
   }

}
```

Here is an exaggerated example to show you the media queries working, adjust your browser to above/under 800px:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1keobbqc/2/)

Comment: Ok, i saw that, but it's still with the problem.. This is a screen of your jsfiddle (still with the problem): http://i.imgur.com/FCNimVF.png And this is a screen of the result i'm looking for: http://i.imgur.com/fgeF3r0.png I know i could use transparency border in a normal div. But since i'm looking for a responsive website, that method didn't worked well for me

Comment: No, the screenshot i got was from your jsfiddle @jmore009

Comment: Ok just checking. You need to resize your screen below 800px to see the effect, but read my explanation, its just an example of using media queries. I'm not on your screen size so its hard to actually fix your issue. Im suggesting how you fix it by adjusting your angle on using media queries. Does that make sense? @CelsomTrindade

Comment: Yes, i understood that. But even if i change the angle, it's only working on small screen. On bigger screen like mine (1080p) it's not working. I tried to use a negative margin.. I can elimate the space between last skewed div and footer.. But not between footer and body. On small screen it's working fine, but do you know another solution for big screens?

Comment: I dont think you quite understand what im saying. You use the media queries for your size, so my example has `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)` change the 800 to something like 2000 or whatever suites you, and you could use multiple media queries

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to keep the angle constant, and want to make sure that the left side adjusts perfectly, just state

```
transform-origin: left bottom;
```

this way, the vertical distance between the footer and the bottom at the left border will be constant (but the right size of the footer will be lower as the width of the page increases)